# i got some error during installation of contiki os while running cooja simulator

Tags: embedded-linux

```
 ~/contiki-ng/tools/cooja$ ant run 
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.   We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/bin/java
```

somebody plz help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Probably won't surprise you if we say that we need more details to be able to help. What distribution are you using? On what architecture? What is the output of  the `file /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/bin/java` command?

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

open termial
type `java -version`
if this is not java8
then install java8

```
whereis java
```

copy this path_where_java

or do this directly

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

Manually select java8 version

terminal

```
gedit .bashrc
```

write

```
export JAVA_HOME=path_where_java
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

do something for .profile

```
gedit .profile
```

write

```
export JAVA_HOME=path_where_java
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

RESTART